# Rails Bootstrap, styling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap.  I am trying to style the following anchor tag color

```html
a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

I can change the color in inspect elements but I can't seem to locate it in my app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss file

```html
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#logo:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #777;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}
```

welcome/index.html.erb

```html
<div class="center jumbotron">


<h1><%= link_to 'THE M.A.D. BLOGGER', controller: 'articles' %></h1>


  <%= link_to image_tag("rounder.gif", alt: "logo"),
            controller: 'articles' %>

<div>
  <%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I neglected to style the anchor tag in my stylesheets/custom.css.scss

```html
a {

  color: black;

}
```

I mistook default styling in Inspect Elements as existing stylesheets/custom.css.scss